# Modern textbooks on quantum mechanics

Tags: quantum-mechanics, soft-question, resource-recommendations

I'm looking for modern textbooks on quantum mechanics that treat topics such as quantum entanglement , bell's theorem , quantum teleportation , quantum information theory , The Many-world interpretation , decoherence etc . All the textbooks that I can find cover the usual topics only (scattering theory , perturbation , the hydrogen atom etc ) But I can't find a book that mainly address these topics . Are there textbooks that specialize in the aforementioned topics ? If not , What are some pedagogical papers that are useful ?

I don't care if the resources are mathematically rigorous or not . I would actually prefer books /papers that use more advanced math than usual.